# Issues with justification

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I was going through this tex files www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/8400/HQuick_cv.tex‎. However, when I use this tex, the text is not justified properly

[image]

See the words establishments, Experimental are crossing the margin. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you loading `babel` with `english` option?

Comment: @Sigur. Yes Sigur

Comment: The referenced file does not use babel

Answer (score 6):

Please make questions self contained. However the referenced file disables all hyphenation after the first section. which presumably was not intended. Comment out the offending line

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   \hyphenpenalty=10000%
    \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright #1}}}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}
```

The file also uses a lot of obsolete LaTeX 2.09 font commands such as `\bf` and `\em`